# LLVM-General segmentation fault

Tags: haskell, llvm

I have two LLVM.General.Module modules, A and B.  My goal is to link B into A and then write the assembly to a file.  I am playing for the moment with a toy program to see how to use the LLVM-General interface.  I have used the LLVM-General-Pure package to create LLVM.General.AST modules for some compiler backends.

I would like to take these ASTs into the C++ world (LLVM.General.Module), link them, and then write the assembly.  I found the error while linking the C++ modules, but I have a feeling that the error is in the way I produce the C++ objects.  Here is what I did:

```
convASTToModE ast = do
a <- withContext $ \context -> do
    x <- runErrorT $ withModuleFromAST context ast $ \mod -> return mod 
    return x
return a
```

Comment: I couldn't find a function of type Module -> Module (like moduleAST to make the AST from the C++ object when using, say withModuleFromLLVMAssembly) to give to withModuleFromAST, so that I get a Module back, so I just used the unit.  My reading of this is that I can do something with the module I get from the ast, and I just want the module, so I just took it.  I am guessing this is wrong, but figured it would do something.

When I execute this code on one of my LLVM.General.AST.Module modules, the code seems to run fine.  But when I try to use it, it breaks.  For example, if x is a LLVM.General.AST.Module, and I do

```
mod <- convASTToModE x
case mod of
    Left _ -> error ""
    Right mod' -> do
        assemb <- moduleLLVMAssembly mod
        putStrLn assemb
```

I get a segmentation fault.

LLVM-General-3.4.3.0
LLVM-3.4

UPDATE:
I tried the following:

```
writeASTToLLVMAssembly ast filename = do
    withContext $ \context -> do
        runErrorT $ withModuleFromAST context ast $ \mod -> do
            runErrorT $ writeLLVMAssemblyToFile (File filename) mod
    return ()
```

Gives:

```
*** Error in `./LLVMImportAndLinkTest': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer:
0x00000000012db000 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

However,

```
showLLVMAssFromAST ast = do
    str <- withContext $ \context -> do
       str2 <- runErrorT $ withModuleFromAST context ast $ \mod -> do
            str3 <- moduleLLVMAssembly mod 
            return str3
       return str2
    case str of 
         Left _ -> error "ast not convertible to string"
         Right st -> return st
```

Gives no problems.

LLVM-General.3.4.3.0
LLVM-3.4

For example, with the LLVM.General.AST.Module found
http://lpaste.net/106407

That is the pretty printed version of the AST obtained by uploading
http://lpaste.net/106408
into LLVM-General.

That LLVM assembly was generated from Clang by compiling a C file.

Comment: Can you share some more context so that your problem is reproducible and the version information for llvm-general and LLVM.

Comment: I added more detail for you.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Might want to try the Git version of llvm-general 3.4.3.1, it appears to be have been a issue with the library that was fixed this weekend.  https://github.com/bscarlet/llvm-general/issues/109

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't realize it was a bug!  This does indeed fix the issue.

Comment: @StephenDiehl since your comment answered the question and fixed the issue, mind submitting it an an answer to remove this from the unanswered queue?

Comment: @sclv Submitted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to upgrade the version of llvm-general by changing the llvm-general dependency to `llvm-general >= 3.4.3` which fixes a known bug in the implementation.